# Caixa de duas opções de formulário

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um formulário que apresenta uma caixa que tem duas opções, um representa *aceito* e a outra *não aceito*. Acontece que quando o usuário usa para enviar o email ele consegue enviar mesmo com o botão marcando *não aceito*. Há alguma maneira de que eu possa fazer com que valide isso?

*HTML*:

```
<div class="form">
   <h4>Valor do consórcio: <span class="slider-value quote-form-element" data-name="Valor | Automóvel" data-slider-id="consorcio-auto">R$ <span></span></span></h4>
   <div class="slider" data-slider-min="20000" data-slider-max="100000" data-slider-start="23192" data-slider-step="1000" data-slider-id="consorcio-auto"></div>
   <h4>Seus dados:</h4>
   <input type="text" name="Nome" placeholder="Nome..." class="quote-form-element" />
   <input type="text" name="Cidade" placeholder="Cidade/UF..." class="quote-form-element quote-form-client-email last" />                           
   <input type="text" name="Número de Telefone" placeholder="Telefone..." class="quote-form-element telefone" />
   <input type="text" name="Endereço de Email" placeholder="E-mail..." class="quote-form-element quote-form-client-email last contact_email" />
   <h4>Política de Privacidade</h4>
   <div class="checkbox quote-form-element" data-checked="yes" data-name="Política de Privacidade">
      <span class="checkbox-status"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
      <span class="checkbox-values">
      <span class="checkbox-value-checked" style="font-size: 12px">Li e aceito a politica de privacidade</span>
      <span class="checkbox-value-unchecked">Não aceito</span> 
      </span>
   </div>
   <button class="button button-navy-blue send-quote" type="button">Simular meu consórcio <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i></button>
   <div class="quote-form-thanks">
      <div class="quote-form-thanks-content">
         Obrigado pelo seu interesse, retornaremos em breve ;). 
         <span class="quote-form-thanks-close">Fechar</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

*Javascript:*

```
$('.send-quote').click(function() {

    var quoteForm = $(this).parent();
    var quoteFormParent = quoteForm.parent().parent();

    var insuranceType = quoteFormParent.data('quote-form-for');
    var fields = {};
    var fieldID = 0;

    var fieldName = '';
    var fieldValue = '';

    var clientName = '';
    var clientEmail = '';

    var errorFound = false;

    quoteForm.find('.quote-form-element').each(function(fieldID) {

        fieldName = $(this).attr('name');
        if (typeof fieldName == 'undefined' || fieldName === false) {

            fieldName = $(this).data('name');
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('checkbox')) {

            fieldValue = $(this).data('checked') == 'yes' ? $(this).children('.checkbox-values').children('.checkbox-value-checked').text() : $(this).children('.checkbox-values').children('.checkbox-value-unchecked').text();
        } else {

            fieldValue = $(this).is('input') || $(this).is('select') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
            if (($(this).is('input') && fieldValue == '') || ($(this).is('select') && fieldValue == '-')) {

                errorFound = true;
                $(this).addClass('error');
            } else {

                $(this).removeClass('error');
            }
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('quote-form-client-name')) clientName = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).hasClass('quote-form-client-email')) clientEmail = $(this).val();

        fields[fieldID] = {
            'name': fieldName,
            'value': fieldValue
        };
        fieldID++;

    });

    if (errorFound == false) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '_assets/submit.php',
            data: {
                'send': 'quote-form',
                'values': fields,
                'clientName': clientName,
                'clientEmail': clientEmail
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output) {

                quoteForm.children('.quote-form-thanks').fadeIn(300);
            }

        });
    }

});
```

[Página](http://consorciomenegalli.com.br/teste/) que apresenta o conteúdo no menu *Simulação*.

Comment: Normalmente é apenas um checkbox, se não marca-lo, o formulário não permite ser enviado...

Comment: Não entendi porque usa o <span> em vês de < input type="checkbox" />, ai seria somente realizar a validação de qual input esta checado. Se não entendi errado.

Comment: usa o `Event.PreventDefault()` se o checkbox estiver marcado. Vai impedir que seu formulario seja enviado.

Comment: se não aceito vc da um `$("#iddoform").hide();` no onclik fo jquery